# Pandas: select rows from columns using Regex

Tags: regex, pandas

I want to extract rows from column `feccandid` that have a H or S as the first value:

```
    cid     amount  date    catcode     feccandid
0   N00031317   1000    2010    B2000   H0FL19080
1   N00027464   5000    2009    B1000   H6IA01098
2   N00024875   1000    2009    A5200   S2IL08088
3   N00030957   2000    2010    J2200   S0TN04195
4   N00026591   1000    2009    F3300   S4KY06072
5   N00031317   1000    2010    B2000   P0FL19080
6   N00027464   5000    2009    B1000   P6IA01098
7   N00024875   1000    2009    A5200   S2IL08088
8   N00030957   2000    2010    J2200   H0TN04195
9   N00026591   1000    2009    F3300   H4KY06072
```

I am using this code:

```
campaign_contributions.loc[campaign_contributions['feccandid'].astype(str).str.extractall(r'^(?:S|H)')]
```

Returns error:
`ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups`

Does anyone with experience using Regex know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something this simple, you can bypass the regex:

```
relevant = campaign_contributions.feccandid.str.startswith('H') | \
    campaign_contributions.feccandid.str.startswith('S')
campaign_contributions[relevant]
```

However, if you want to use a regex, you can change this to

```
relevant = ~campaign_contributions['feccandid'].str.extract(r'^(S|H)').isnull()
```

Note that the `astype` is redundant, and that `extract` is enough.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use `str.match` instead of extract and negate?

ie   `df[df['col'].str.match(r'^(S|H)')]`

(I came here looking for the same answer, but the use of extract seemed odd, so I found the docs for `str.ops`.

W

Comment: While both answers are functional, this is a much nicer solution.